# "Rolling up" groups in Jaspersoft iReport

Tags: sql, jasper-reports, ireport

I have a profit and loss report that currently has three levels of grouping:
1. Pharmacy
2. Customer
3. Packaging Type

I've set up the report to prompt the user to provide values for pharmacy, customer, and packaging type. The detail band displays measures like revenue and margin. Selecting the default for pharmacy, customer, or packaging type returns all values in the group.

I'm wondering - is there any way, if the user selects "use default" for a parameter, to tell iReport to roll up the grouping? Right now, if I select a pharmacy and a customer but use the default for packaging type, I still get a detail band for each of several packaging types. How can I tell iReport to sum on ALL packaging types? Or, if no customer is specified, sum on ALL customers for a given pharmacy? Or could I do it in the query? I have an Oracle database and am using iReport Professional 4.5.1.

Thanks,
Lisa

EDITED TO ADD CODE:

```
 SELECT
      FAC.FILL_MONTH AS FILL_MO,
      FAC.PHAR_CODE AS PHAR_CODE,
      FAC.FAC_ID AS FAC_ID,
      FAC.PACKTYPE_CODE AS PACKTYPE,
      SUM(FAC.TOT_RXCOUNT_NUM) AS RX_COUNT,
      SUM(FAC.TOT_REVENUE_AMT) AS REVENUE,
      SUM(FAC.TOT_COGS_AMT) AS COGS,
      SUM(FAC.TOT_MARGIN_AMT) AS MARGIN
 FROM
      MySchema.Table FAC
 WHERE
      FAC.FILL_MONTH BETWEEN $P{startdate} AND $P{enddate}
      AND $X{IN, FAC.PHAR_CODE, pharmacy}
      AND $X{IN, FAC.FAC_ID, facility}
      AND $X{IN, FAC.PACKTYPE_CODE, packtype}
 GROUP BY
      FAC.PHAR_CODE,
      FAC.FAC_ID,
      FAC.PACKTYPE_CODE,
      FAC.FILL_MONTH
 ORDER BY
      PHAR_CODE ASC,
      FAC_ID ASC,
      PACKTYPE ASC,
      FILL_MO ASC
```

Comment: Post your SQL (or a simplified version of it). It should be possible to use the parameters to get what you need.

Comment: Thank you! I posted a simplified version of my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the SQL correct to get exactly the raw data that you want. But you'll need to modify it to force the `PACKTYPE` (and other fields) to group differently in the special case where the user specifies no `PACKTYPE`.

Create a new parameter `$P{PACKTYPE_SELECT_SQL}`. Its default value is directly based on the value of your existing parameter `$P{packtype}`. (This means `$P{packtype}` must appear first in the .jrxml.) Set `$P{PACKTYPE_SELECT_SQL}`'s default value to something like this:

```
$P{packtype}==null ? " 'All Package Types' " : " FAC.PACKTYPE_CODE "
```

Then modify the SQL query like this (only a single line is modified, the rest is just for context):

```
SELECT
     FAC.FILL_MONTH AS FILL_MO,
     FAC.PHAR_CODE AS PHAR_CODE,
     FAC.FAC_ID AS FAC_ID,
     $P!{PACKTYPE_SELECT_SQL} AS PACKTYPE,
...
WHERE
     FAC.FILL_MONTH BETWEEN $P{startdate} AND $P{enddate}
     AND $X{IN, FAC.PHAR_CODE, pharmacy}
     AND $X{IN, FAC.FAC_ID, facility}
     AND $X{IN, FAC.PACKTYPE_CODE, packtype}
```

In the case where `$P{packtype}` is not null then the generated SQL will be exactly as it was before. But in the case where `$P{packtype}` is null you'll now get a hard-coded string in place of the PACKTYPE_CODE.

Presumably your report is grouping on `PACKTYPE`. So you should be able to leave the layout and grouping in the report unchanged.

You could imagine variations like adding a Boolean input control to explicitly let the user choose whether to keep the PACKTYPEs in the report or not. But this basic idea should get you what you need.

Comment: This works beautifully. Thank you so much for your help! I hadn't thought about defining another parameter so I could use $P! in that way. I can see myself using this often.

Comment: Very interesting.  I've never done that before.  A very creative solution.

Comment: Matthew, I deployed this to JasperServer and set up cascading input controls for the facility and packtype values. It works in iReport but not in JasperServer. None of the input controls is mandatory and in JasperServer I unchecked "always prompt." When the report first opens, it rolls up the groups like it is supposed to, but from the input controls, if I only select a pharmacy and don't select any other input controls, it shows all elements of the other input controls, like the _select_sql parameters are ignored. Any thoughts on what I can do to fix this? Thank you again.

Comment: Is the problem with the contents of the cascading input control lists? Or with the contents of the report? (or both?) I would start with printing the contents of all params in the title band to determine with certainty where the problem starts.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! The report was producing null values when I first opened it, but submitting empty input controls produced empty lists. I am using collection variables. I edited my parameters to handle both null values and empty lists and now it works perfectly. I will post a more detailed explanation on the question that I created specifically for this problem.

Answer (score 2):

I would attempt to do it in the query. It is hard to give specifics without seeing your query, but I can provide some code of mine as an example. In this particular jasper report, I am displaying values based on a user-specified PGM_NAME and USER_NAME. However, specifying those parameters is optional. If a parameter is not specified, the default is to report for all PGM_NAMEs and/or USER_NAMEs. In my ireport query, the WHERE clause has the following lines:

```
WHERE   ($P{PGM_NAME} IS NULL OR job.pgm_name = $P{PGM_NAME})
AND     ($P{USER_NAME} IS NULL OR details.username = $P{USER_NAME})
```

This works like a charm. I hope this is helpful to you in determining how you can adjust your own query. If you would like assistance with this, please post the query itself in your question.

Comment: Pharmacy, customer, and packaging type are all variables of type java.util.collection, and in my query's where clause I set parameters using $X, like $X{IN, PHARMACIES, pharmacy}.

So your answer has made me realize that when I use the default for pharmacy/customer/packaging type, it returns every value for each of those. I don't want a distinct value for each, I want the group aggregate. I just need to figure out how to tell iReport that.

Comment: It looks like we can specify more data (using $X{... to get every packaging type for a given customer, or just one type, or multiple types) but it doesn't appear that we can manipulate the number of grouping levels in a JRXML template on the fly.