# The report's SQL query with LIKE

Tags: jasper-reports

I'm trying to  write the SQL query in *iReport* with  LIKE syntaxis.
I write query with :

```
... AND voc_agent.id LIKE '%$P!{LABEL}%'
```

It is works. But know I want check the P{LABEL} on NULL
I wrote

```
... $P!{LABELL}
$P!{LABELL} = ($P!{LABEL}==null? "" :"AND voc_agent.id LIKE '%" + $P{LABEL}+ "%'")
```

The result is :

```
Error filling print... Error evaluating expression :      Source text : ($P{LABEL} == null ? "" : "AND voc_agent_commercial_terms.label LIKE '%" + $P{LABEL} + "%'")
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What kind of database are you using?

Answer (score 1):

afaik conditional expressions are not working in queries. how about using a variable instead?
put your conditional expression into a string variable and use the variable inside the query.

Or see the link that lisa posted: 
["Rolling up" groups in Jaspersoft iReport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10897962/rolling-up-groups-in-jaspersoft-ireport)

it's a much better answer ;)

Comment: Matt Dahlman helped me with something similar in the past, so here is a link to his example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10897962/rolling-up-groups-in-jaspersoft-ireport