# JasperReports Server: multi select query - default value 'All'

Tags: parameters, jasper-reports, jasperserver

How can I add a default value expression so that all the items in my multi select query parameter are selected.. (default value = 'All')

It's not a static list, but an SQL query

Comment: possible duplicate of [JasperServer - null values for input controls](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11082379/jasperserver-null-values-for-input-controls)

Comment: No that's a totally different thing? I don't have null values.. I just want that jasperserver select all my checkboxes when I run a report. Now it's always the firs item and I have to click on 'All' to select all the items

Comment: You can use the solution from the that post

Comment: Do you want the report to select and display each value, or roll them up into an "all" category? In addition to the question that Alex linked to, here's another one where I worked with the same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10897962/rolling-up-groups-in-jaspersoft-ireport.

Comment: select each checkbox in my multi select query parameter.. I don't have an option 'All' and I don't want it

Answer (score 0):

See these posts if you want to roll up your parameter selections into one category.

[Rolling up groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10897962/rolling-up-groups-in-jaspersoft-ireport)

[Null values for input controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11082379/jasperserver-null-values-for-input-controls)

If you want to display each value, use the $X{IN... clause (see [the iReport Ultimate Guide](http://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/ireport-ultimate-guide)):

```
SELECT *
FROM   MyCustomers
WHERE  $X{IN, customer_id, customer_parameter}
```

If you don't make a selection in $P{customer_parameter}, the clause will become 0=0 and will not constrain on customer_id.